# facebook-php-sdk loginurl api error code 100

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create a facebook login url using Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.0) from 
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk
below is my code

```
$config = array(    'appId'  => '***',  
                    'secret' => '***',  
                    'cookie' => true 
                    );
require_once("facebook.php");

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$params = array('scope' => 'user_birthday, user_location, email',
                'redirect_uri' => "http://my_domain.in/user/fb",    
                'display' => 'popup'
                );
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

the problem is when the loginUrl is clicked it will give error from facebook as below:

> API Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error
>   Message: Display type **popup**. isn't valid on www.facebook.com. You
>   should access a different domain (m.facebook.com, www.facebook.com),
>   or use one of the following supported display types: page, **popup**,
>   iframe, touch, none

the question is where did i go wrong?
fyi, the very same code were fine before, somehow it's not working now, i kinda missed when the problem actually happen at first, but in between i did upgrade the facebook-php-sdk from 3.1.1 to 3.2.0, n possibly the domain and url settings in my facebook app.

> app domain : my_domain.in
>   site url : http://www.my_domain.in

furthermore,
even my i changed the params into

```
$params = array('scope' => 'user_birthday, user_location, email',
                'redirect_uri' => "http://my_domain.in/user/fb"
                );
```

i still receive an error with different message

> API Error Code: 100
>   API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>   Error Message: Unsupported scope: '**email**.'. Supported scopes: ads_management create_event create_note **email** export_stream friends_about_me friends_activities friends_birthday friends_checkins friends_education_history friends_events friends_games_activity friends_groups friends_hometown friends_interests friends_likes friends_location friends_notes friends_online_presence friends_photo_video_tags friends_photos friends_questions friends_relationship_details friends_relationships friends_religion_politics friends_status friends_subscriptions friends_videos friends_website friends_work_history manage_friendlists manage_notifications manage_pages offline_access photo_upload publish_actions publish_checkins publish_stream read_friendlists read_insights read_mailbox read_page_mailboxes read_requests read_stream rsvp_event share_item sms status_update user_about_me user_activities user_birthday user_checkins user_education_history user_events user_games_activity user_groups user_hometown user_interests user_likes user_location user_notes user_online_presence user_photo_video_tags user_photos user_questions user_relationship_details user_relationships user_religion_politics user_status user_subscriptions user_videos user_website user_work_history video_upload xmpp_login

please help,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

the problem was there was an additional character (a dot) in my href attribute,
as coded below

```
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>.">
```

noticed it after reviewing again the error message (popup**.** email**.**).

it simply worked when i removed the character.
so it is not caused by the facebook-php-sdk version nor the domain/url settings in my facebook app.

sorry for any trouble caused.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the `display` parameter in this scenario, because you are only creating a URL – and URLs themselves do not contain any ability to tell “I want to be opened in a popup”.

This parameter is mostly for calling dialogs using the `FB.ui` method out of the JS SDK.

Just remove the entry from your `$params` array, then it should work.

Comment: thank you @CBroe for the response, appreciate it. the problem is fixed now, as i posted below.